# What is the purpose of styles.xml file in android?

Tags: android, android-styles

What is the purpose of style.xml file in andorid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can declare your app theme and much more styles that used same xml eliments like:

```
<style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
```

XML file that applies the style to a TextView (saved in res/layout/):

```
<EditText
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

By style="@style/customText"  you apply all of it's propertise in single line.

Hope it helps